# Query a list in another list in C#

Tags: c#

I have a class like that

```
public class Tbl
{
    public List<Row> Rows {get; set;}
}
public class Row
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Value {get; set;}
}
//Using the class  
//Add rows to Tbl
Tbl t = new Tbl();
t.Rows.Add(new Row() {Name = "Row1", Value = "Row1Value"};
t.Rows.Add(new Row() {Name = "Row2", Value = "Row2Value"};
t.Rows.Add(new Row() {Name = "Row3", Value = "Row3Value"};

//Now I want to select the Row2 in this list, usually, I use this way
public Row GetRow(this Tbl t, string RowName)
{
    return t.Rows.Where(x => x.Name == RowName).FirstOrDefault();
}
Row r = t.GetRow("Row2");
//But I would like to use that way
Row r = t.Rows["Row2"];
```

How can I do that.

Thanks for every comments.

Comment: Make sure you initialize Rows, at least in this example code it is always null and will throw an error when you try to add to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extension properties do not exist, but you could use a wrapper around `List<Row>` and add an [Indexer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) to it.

```
public class RowList : List<Row> {

    public Row this[string key] {
        get { return this.Where( x => x.Name == key ).FirstOrDefault(); }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Tbl
{
    public RowList Rows { get; set; }
}

Tbl t = new Tbl();
// ...
Row r = t.Rows["Row2"];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a string indexer in yout Tbl class

```
public Row this[string s]
{
    get
    {
        return Rows.Where(x => x.Name == s).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Then you use like:

```
Row r = t["Row2"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to add an [indexed property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) to your `Tbl` type:

```
public class Tbl
{
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }

    public Row this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            return Rows.Where(r => r.Name == name).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will make you be able to do `t["Row2"]`, but not `t.Rows["Row2"]`.

Comment: @tusbar: True, and if that's what the OP needs then they should take look at your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need there is an [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx), which would allow you to do t["Row2"] - I'm not sure how easily you could use that to do t.Rows["Row2"] though.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Tbl class:

```
  public Row this[string name] {
     get { return Rows.Where(r => r.Name == name).FirstOrDefault(); }
  }
```